# Update a scope variable value with Phaser and typescript in an ionic 2 app

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope, ionic2, phaser-framework

I am trying to create a game application with Ionic 2 (which uses TypeScript) and Phaser.io. So far everything was good and my game works but ...

I can launch Phaser action inside a TypeScript function but I can't do the contrary.

For example, I have a score defined in my html by `{{ score }}` inside my TypeScript controller I init this score with `this.score = 0;` Then I can update the score inside a TypeScript function. But inside any phaser function (preload,create,update,render) it doesn't work any more. An example in the image below (which is a similar simpler version of my code).

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPu1b.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to inject ChangeDetectionRef and then calling detectChanges()?

Comment: Sorry I don't have strong knowledge about that ... Do you have an example of how that works ?

Comment: Instead of adding an image with your code, it would be better to copy/paste your code into your question itself. I also tried to clean up your question but your third paragraph needs a bit more work if you could help clarify what you're asking there.

Answer (score 0):

i am fairly new to Ionic & Phaser combo. From what i understand, when we do

```
this.game = new Phaser.Game(width, height, renderer, parent, state, transparent, antialias, physicsConfig)
```

the **state** creates a new scope(for Phaser), so you won't have the same 'this' inside Ionic's 'ionViewDidEnter()' and in Phaser's 'create()'.

What i did(and i don't know if it's the best solution), was to add

```
this.game = new Phaser.Game(width, height, renderer, parent, state)
this.game.ionic = this; // reference ionic Object to Phaser Object
```

Now i can call ionic from inside Phaser

```
create() {
  this.game.ionic.alert.present();
}
```